# Фильтр товаров в админке Opencart

Tags: opencart

Вкладка "Код" подключена к столбцу col5 в базе данных, как подключить ее к столбцу col6 к примеру ?

Comment: Опишите свой вопрос более подробно.

Comment: @Vuland какое расширение для админки используете? в дефолтном шаблоне "Кода" нет, есть "Модель" и сетка col-sm-4. а по кастомным шаблонам и расширениям мы не угадаем.